# Which technique should I use to generate a dynamic form in Angular 9

Tags: angular, angular9, angular-forms

I have a page that has a formGroup. The fields in the form Group are all required. On the layout bellow the form related to this formGroup. I will have a button to add additional information. This information is optional. When the button is clicked, the optional form will repeatedly appears. For example. I want to add a person's contact. I add name, telephone, address. Then I can add more contact information by clicking on the "add additional contact". Then a form containing "address and telephone" will continually appear on the page. What technique can I use to add these dynamic fields?

Comment: there are only two way of doing forms in angular,
template-driven forms and reactive forms. From your description, it looks like you are searching for a reactive form implementation (with the `formBuilder`).

Comment: I want to think on the posibilities before starting. I have to show a chuck of template. Maybe interate some property of formGroup to repeteadly show the form...

Comment: Use reactive forms. Template driven is easy but limited. As soon as the need is complex, you will need some reactive forms. That being said, you have 2 options : creating all `FormControl` from the beginning and show/hide them OR you create them dynamically with `new FormControl(undefined, Validators.required)` or using `FormBuilder`.

Comment: Also, it depends : can I add 3 mobile phones for example ? If yes, create the `FormControl`s dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You could:

- create a reusable component for the dynamic field/form
- in your button you add the struct data empty in your property(an array) in the model data
- in the template you observe this property and load the component if you have the data.

Answer (score 0):

For this use case, you should use some Reactive Forms. They will help you to handle the dynamic part.

You have several ways of doing that :

- Create all `FormControl` from the very beginning then reveal/hide them when the user chooses them
- Use a `FormArray`, create some `FormControl` dynamically and add them to the `FormArray` like you would do with an array
- Use a `FormGroup`, create some `FormControl` dynamically and add them to the `FormGroup` like you would add some properties to an object.

Here is a [StackBlitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-ssjztx?file=src/app/app.component.html) showing how to do it with a `FormArray`

It is based on the Angular documentation about [Reactive Forms](https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms)

Here are the essentials parts :

How to create the `FormArray`, add/remove `FormControl` :

**app.component.ts**

```js
export class AppComponent  {

  formArray = new FormArray([]);
  formGroup = new FormGroup({ 'array': this.formArray });

  constructor() {
    this.addControl();
    console.log('yolo', this.formArray);
  }

  addControl() {
    this.formArray.push(new FormControl('YOLO', [Validators.required]));
  }

  delete(index) {
    this.formArray.controls.splice(index, 1);
    this.formArray.updateValueAndValidity();
  }
}
```

How to iterate on the `FormArray`/`FormControls`:

**app.component.html**

```html
<form [formGroup]="formGroup">
    <div formArrayName="array">
        <div *ngFor="let control of formArray.controls; let i=index">
            <input type="text" [formControlName]="i"/>
            <button (click)="delete(i)">Delete</button>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button id="btnAddControl" (click)="addControl()">Add control</button>
</form>
```

As a bonus, here is a piece of code which helps you to easily track the value of the `FormArray` while you are developing :

```html
<pre>{{ formArray.value | json }}</pre>
```